# Hive - dependencies while running Java Code

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

What are the settings and the jar files needed for running the following code. I have jdk1.8.0_05, Hadoop 2.2.0 and Hive 0.12.0. Please Help.
I am trying to run this code on eclipse but it is not compiling. I have added about 15 external jars but to no use

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.DriverManager;

public class HiveJdbcClient {
  private static String driverName = "org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    try {
      Class.forName(driverName);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.exit(1);
    }
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hive://localhost:10000/default", "", "");
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    String tableName = "testHiveDriverTable";
    stmt.executeQuery("drop table " + tableName);
    ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("create table " + tableName + " (key int, value string)");
    // show tables
    String sql = "show tables '" + tableName + "'";
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    if (res.next()) {
       System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }
    // describe table
    sql = "describe " + tableName;
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(res.getString(1) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
    }

    // load data into table
    // NOTE: filepath has to be local to the hive server
    // NOTE: /tmp/a.txt is a ctrl-A separated file with two fields per line
    String filepath = "/tmp/a.txt";
    sql = "load data local inpath '" + filepath + "' into table " + tableName;
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

    // select * query
    sql = "select * from " + tableName;
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(String.valueOf(res.getInt(1)) + "\t" + res.getString(2));
    }

    // regular hive query
    sql = "select count(1) from " + tableName;
    System.out.println("Running: " + sql);
    res = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
    while (res.next()) {
      System.out.println(res.getString(1));
    }
  }
}
```

Error::

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372) at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:259) at HiveJdbcClient.main(HiveJdbcClient.java:15)

Comment: what are the generated errors?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add hive-jdbc-xxxx.jar to your classpath. I do not know what Hadoop version or Hadoop distribution you have, but if you are using last Cloudera distribution, download **hive-0.12.0-cdh5.0.2.tar.gz** from [this archive](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh5/cdh/5/) and include **/hive-0.12.0-cdh.5.0.2/hive-jdbc-0.12.0-cdh5.0.2.jar** into your java classpath.

Answer (score 0):

Following steps will help fix issue:

1. Replace drive class as `org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver`
2. Add `hive-jdbc-<version>.jar`, `common-logging-<version>.jar` & `hadoop-common-<version>.jar` to classpath